# PCB Review (ATmega32U4 + Bosch BNO055 IMU sensor)

Tags: pcb, layout, pcb-layers

So I'm very new to PCB design and would like to get feedback on the layout I've done. I've attached the layers for the board which is a 4-layer stack-up. I'm working with some space constraints too so it looks a bit messy.

The editor I'm using is Easyeda so the footprint / silkscreens are taken from there.

So the green line on the bottom layer is the silkscreen.

[image]

```
                         Image taken from PCBway website
```

For the usb-c connector the slikscreen included in my pcb doesn't show the "PCB edge", so the green outline that extends past the edge of the PCB is showing the rest of the connector. Sorry if its a bit confusing because I just used the ones by the manufacturer.

As for polarity indication, the only components I used that require it are the diodes which are indicated as such. Besides this, I'll generate a CPL file that shows the orientation of the components.

[image]

SCHEMATIC
[image]

TOP LAYER
[image]

PWR LAYER
[image]

GND LAYER
[image]

BOTTOM LAYER
[image]

Comment: Can you turn off transparency so that only the copper is visible?

Comment: sorry not sure if i understand your comment correctly, but you would like me to basically show layer by layer without the overlapping right?

Comment: Yes. I can’t see if you have/how much the inner layers are compromised.

Comment: got it, thankss for clarifying, i've re-uploaded the images as requested! Hope this is clearer! Do let me know if there's anything else!

Comment: If the purple line isn't the card edge then what is it?

Comment: The purple line shows the outline of the board, in the bottom layer there's a portion protruding as it's the usb-c connector

Comment: Hmm ok so green lines on bottom layer isn't silk screen but some mechanical layer?

Comment: What I'm getting to is that the green lines seem to be used to indicate polarity of the crystal, which is info that the assembly contractor will like to know. If not through silk screen, then how? Same thing with all components that have polarity (LEDs etc).

Comment: Oo i see the confusion, hold on, I'll edit the post to explain!

Comment: Edited the post, hope it helps to clarify

Comment: Power layer is very under-utilized. What does the three thin traces do? Can they be routed mostly on top and bottom layers using some vias to not be so long on the power layer and pour power on the rest?